# how to get multiple textbox in table using foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php

```
<table>
<?php
   `extract($_POST);`
   `$objorderdetails = new Dairy_System();`

   `$result=$objorderdetails->getCustomerName();`

   foreach($result as $row)
   {
     $result1=$objorderdetails->getOrderDetails();
     foreach ($result1 as $row1)
     {
?>
<tr>   
  <td><?php echo($row['UserName']); ?></td>
  <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" value="<?php echo($row1['Quantity']); ?>">
  <?php
    if($row['Quantity']==NULL && $row['Quantity']==""){
      $row['Quantity']=0;
    }
  ?>
  </td>  
</tr>
<?php
    }
  }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your question? Is it how to build the html checkbox code in the html table? Explain what your issue is, and an example of what your result would look like

Comment: I want to get textbox in a table where if data comes from a database then return with fillable data, otherwise, a textbox with fillable data value is 0 in a textbox(in a foreach loop) How??.

Comment: So, is that data in `$row['Quantity']` or in `$row1['Quantity']`?

Comment: $row1['Quantity'].

Answer (score 0):

Use input array. ex, `name="Quantity"`

```
<table>
<?php
                    `extract($_POST);`
                    `$objorderdetails = new Dairy_System();`

                    `$result=$objorderdetails->getCustomerName();`

                  foreach($result as $row)
                  {
                    $result1=$objorderdetails->getOrderDetails();
                    foreach ($result1 as $row1)
                    {
                   ?>
                    <tr>   
                      <td><?php echo($row['UserName']); ?></td>
                      <td><input type="number" name="Quantity[]" value="<?php echo($row1['Quantity']); ?>">
                        <?php
                          if($row['Quantity']==NULL && $row['Quantity']==""){
                         $row['Quantity']=0;
                        }
                        ?>
                      </td>  
                    </tr>
                  <?php
                  }
                }
 ?>
</table>
```